# How to fetch unique records without using DISTINCT and UNIQUE Keywords?

Tags: sql, oracle

PFB my SQL query without DISTINCT or UNIQUE Keyword,

```
SELECT CLAIM.CLAIM_ID,
CLAIM.ASSESSMENT_UNIT_ID,
HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.ASSESSMENT_UNIT_MEM_ID,
PERSON.PERSON_ID
FROM CLAIM,
  AWARD,
  AWARD_MEMBER,
  HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER,
  PERSON,
  CONDITIONALITY_GROUP
WHERE CLAIM.CLAIM_ID              = AWARD.CLAIM_ID
AND AWARD.AWARD_ID                = AWARD_MEMBER.AWARD_ID
AND AWARD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID     = HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID
AND HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.PERSON_ID    = PERSON.PERSON_ID
AND HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID = CONDITIONALITY_GROUP.HH_MEMBER_ID;
```

and below is result of above query

```
CLAIM_ID    ASSESSMENT_UNIT_ID  ASSESSMENT_UNIT_MEM_ID  PERSON_ID
5000000002  5000000002           1000004                1000004
5000000002  5000000002           1000004                1000004
5000000002  5000000002           1000003                1000003
5000000002  5000000002           1000003                1000003
```

with the help of unique or distinct the issue is solve but it impact the performance of the query so kindly let us know, How to another way?

appreciate for your help in advance :)

Comment: Why not to use `GROUP BY CLAIM.CLAIM_ID,CLAIM.ASSESSMENT_UNIT_ID,HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.ASSESSMENT_UNIT_MEM_ID,PERSON.PERSON_ID`?

Comment: To `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` you often need to `ORDER BY` internally which is an expensive operation. Why don't you just work out why your query is giving you "duplicates" - It doesn't look like you're using `CONDITIONALITY_GROUP` at all. If you use an `EXISTS` instead, and that table is causing duplicates it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Stawros: distinct and group by gives me same performance.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid CONDITIONALITY_GROUP is required to filter out the records.

Comment: Do you have all the columns participating in joins indexed or unique or primary key?

Comment: If the join to `CONDITIONALITY_GROUP` is causing "duplicates" then use `EXISTS` instead to filter it.

Comment: First you need to show us your tables structure

Comment: Why does the query return duplicates as it is?  9 times out of 10, I'd wager that you're missing a join condition.  Since you haven't posted a reproducible test case, however, it's basically impossible for anyone other than you to figure out which join condition is likely to be missing.

Comment: please post also the execution plan. And specify in the question title that you just want a faster distinct rows. What you get from Utsav is what you asked in the title.

Comment: Figure out where the multiples are coming from - in this case I would wager from CONDITIONALITY_GROUP or HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER. as looking like tables that may have many-to-one relationships. In which case you're either missing a join to get the unique set of data, or you might want to join to a subquery of distinct values instead to limit the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (assuming all data types are integer).

This will first add null row to your data. But as you are doing `union`, it will remove duplicates. Then remove duplicates by doing a `minus` of null row.

```
SELECT CLAIM.CLAIM_ID,
CLAIM.ASSESSMENT_UNIT_ID,
HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.ASSESSMENT_UNIT_MEM_ID,
PERSON.PERSON_ID
FROM CLAIM,
AWARD,
AWARD_MEMBER,
HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER,
PERSON,
CONDITIONALITY_GROUP
WHERE CLAIM.CLAIM_ID              = AWARD.CLAIM_ID
AND AWARD.AWARD_ID                = AWARD_MEMBER.AWARD_ID
AND AWARD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID     = HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID
AND HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.PERSON_ID    = PERSON.PERSON_ID
AND HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID = CONDITIONALITY_GROUP.HH_MEMBER_ID

union
select null,null,null,null from dual

minus

select null,null,null,null from dual
```

I tried it with this query and it didn't give any duplicates.

```
(select 1,1,1,1 from dual union all
select 1,1,1,1 from dual union all
select 1,1,2,2 from dual union all
select 1,1,2,2 from dual)
union
select null,null,null,null from dual
minus
select null,null,null,null from dual
```

Output

```
1   1   1   1
1   1   2   2
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your efforts but with the help of above.. cost of query is increase... I am looking for solution through which I can reduce the cost of the query.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance create indexes on the columns which are included in the where clause. For example to create an index on the CLAIM_ID column in the claim table use:

```
create index idx_claimid_claim on CLAIM(CLAIM_ID)
```

You might want to create bit map index or b-tree index based on the data you have in each column.

Comment: claim id is primary key and index is already present on that column.

Comment: I have just given an example..you can add other indexes to improve performance